# Why does Callout pixelate the resulting plot?

Tags: plotting

Somehow, using callout produces a plot that is similar but with the display pixelated (see pasted image below). Im not sure if this is a effect of mac (MacBook Air, M1, 2020, Apple M1, Sonoma 14.3 (23D56)), Mathematica version 13.2

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, Joined -> True]
```

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2}, Callout[{2, 2}, 2], {3, 4}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: On version 13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows they are of the same quality.

Comment: i actually think this has to do with adding any transparency to a graphics. For example in the example mentioned above, setting Callout[... , Background -> None] solves the issue.

Comment: I do not see the issue with macOS Sonoma 14.3, using either MMA version 13.2.1 or 14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

this was solved by increasing the antialiasing quality. see image below

[image]